# querying mails without categories not supported

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are trying to use Microsoft graph to query a mailbox and return us all uncategorized mails.
Following the OData spec here: https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358

We should be able to do something like this:

$filter=Categories/$count eq 0

But the call returns an operation not supported exception.
Is there another way to query for uncategorized Mail messages?

Comment: An engineer will be looking at improving filter functionality for categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying mails without categories doesn't appear to be supported at this time. Please add a feature request to [Microsoft Graph User Voice](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests). I might as well share what I found in case it is useful to someone.

Unfortunately, **the following doesn't work**:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=not categories/any()&$select=categories
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=categories/$count eq 0
```

This will **return all mail with categories**:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=categories/any()&$select=categories
```

This will **return all mail of a particular category**:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/messages?$filter=categories/any(x:x eq 'particular category')&$select=categories
```